# RSA encryption/Decryption in Android

Tags: java, android, cryptography, rsa, java-security

I have `RSA Public-Key` on server side in below format:

```
<string xmlns="http://www.cherripik.com/">
<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>abc</Modulus><Exponent>abc</Exponent></RSAKeyValue>
</string>
```

I have tried almost all possible ways but could not able to `encrypt string` with this public key on android side. Could anyone give me an example in which i will encrypt any of the string like `"abc"` with this public key and also decrypt that encrypted key to back to `"abc"`. It will be very helpful to me.

Advance Thanks.

Below are the ways which i have used but no success. It gave some value but it is not correct.

```
public String encrypt(String message, String Modulus, String Exponent) {
        String outputEncrypted = "";
        try {
             byte[] modulusBytes = Base64Coder.decode(Modulus);
               byte[] exponentBytes = Base64Coder.decode(Exponent);
               BigInteger modulus = new BigInteger(modulusBytes );               
               BigInteger exponent = new BigInteger(exponentBytes);

               RSAPublicKeySpec rsaPubKey = new RSAPublicKeySpec(modulus, exponent);
               KeyFactory fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
               PublicKey pubKey = fact.generatePublic(rsaPubKey);

               Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
               cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pubKey);

               byte[] plainBytes = new String("abc").getBytes("UTF-8");
               byte[] cipherData = cipher.doFinal( plainBytes );
               String encryptedString = new String(Base64Coder.encode(cipherData));
               Log.i(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "encryptedString : "+encryptedString);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
        return outputEncrypted;
    }
```

One more thing when I create encrypted string with above method. It will give 346 characters encrypted string. But on my server, I have only encrypt and decrypt method. On server encrypt method, it will producing 344 character. Lastly when I put my encrypted string to server method to verify that my encrypted string is correct. Server throw this error.

```
<string xmlns="http://www.Myserver.com/">Error occurred while decoding OAEP padding.</string>
```

Comment: This suggests that the server expects OAEP (padding) and not PKCS#1 v1.5 padding. What other parameters does the server expect?

Comment: I don't know. You haven't fully specified what the server expects. Try other Cipher instance strings like `RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-1AndMGF1Padding` or `RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding`.

Comment: Common mistake with BigInteger when creating frym byte[]: it can get negative! Make sure you never get negative values: `BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(1, modulusBytes);`